# How to transfer data from S3 bucket to Kafka

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-kafka

There are examples and documentation on copying data from Kafka topics to S3 but how do you copy data from S3 to Kafka?

Answer (score 2):

[When you read an S3 object, you get a byte stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html). And you can send any byte array to Kafka with `ByteArraySerializer`.

Or you can parse that InputStream to some custom object, then send that [using whatever serializer you can configure](https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-sending-object-as-a-message).

You can find one example of a Kafka Connect process here (which I assume you are comparing to Confluent's S3 Connect writer) - https://jobs.zalando.com/tech/blog/backing-up-kafka-zookeeper/index.html that can be configured to read binary archives or line-delimted text from S3.

Similarly, Apache Spark, Flink, Beam, NiFi, etc. simlar Hadoop related tools can read from S3 and write events to Kafka as well.

---

The *problems* with this approach is that you need to keep track of what files have been read so far, as well as handle partially read files.

Comment: Is there a way to copy the data directly from S3 to Kafka? I want to avoid downloading the data to my application, then uploading the data to Kafka.

Comment: None to my knowledge. Any solution you use must read the data from S3, into memory, then produce it to Kafka

Comment: Note: Kafka is not intended to be used as a file delievery pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon your scenario or desired frequency for uploading the objects, you can either use Lambda function on each event (e.g. every time a file is uploaded) or as a cron. This lambda works as a producer by using Kafka API and publishes to a topic.

**Specifics:**

- The trigger for the Lambda function can be the `s3:PutObject` event coming from [directly s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) or [cloudwatch events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html).
- You can run [lambda as a cron](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html) if you don't need the objects instantly. The alternate in this case could also be running a cron on an EC2 instance which has Kafka producer and permissions to read objects from s3 and it keeps pushing them to the kafka topics.